# Number of calls returns 0 when I pass a function from props to a React component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-testing-library

I have an input field component that gets a function to use on change event. I create a variable, and its setter, then pass that setter to the component

This is the Input component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

export default function Input({
    id,
    type,
    placeholder,
    setter
}: {
    id: string
    type: string
    placeholder: string
    setter: Function
}) {
    return (
            <input
                id={id}
                type={type}
                placeholder={placeholder}
                className="border-[1px] border-zinc-200 rounded-md w-full px-2 py-1 shadow-lg"
                onChange={(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setter(event.target.value)}
                data-testid="input-field"
            />
    )
}
```

I want to write a test for this component and check that when onChange event is fired, setter function will be called. That is what I wrote:

```
import Input from "@/components/Input"
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"

describe('components/Input', () => {
    test('displays label from props', () => {
        const id = 'test-id'
        const type = 'text'
        const placeholder = 'Test input'
        const setter = jest.fn((e: string) => {})
        render(<Input
            id={id}
            type={type}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            setter={setter}
        />)

        const input = screen.getByTestId('input-field')
        fireEvent.input(input, {
            target: { value: 'newValue' }
        })

        expect(setter).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
})
```

As a result, I get a message says

```
   expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                          
    Expected number of calls: 1                                                                                                                                                           
    Received number of calls: 0
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This is strange because I have tested the code and the test is passing. It could be that for some reason fireEvent.input function might not be triggering the input event in your case. You can try the fireEvent.change method instead and see if it works in your case

```js
fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: 'newValue' } })
```